# Vue JS v-select cannot diplaying text from json

Tags: javascript, vue.js, v-select, vue-select

I have difficulty using vue-select (v-select) when editing data. Currently v-select displays the ID, the data that should appear is the text or label.

[image]

```
const detailPresensi = {
      detail_data: [{
          "id": 3,
          "project_id": 1,
          "duration_minute": 300,
          "detail": "Text 1"
      }, {
          "id": 4,
          "project_id": 2,
          "duration_minute": 203,
          "detail": "Text 2"
      }]
    }

    let options = {
      "1": "AAA",
      "2": "BBB",
      "3": "CCC",
    };
```

here is the script: [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/andreasdan/afwy6k9n/88/)

My expectations:
if the data array in detail_data has project_id: 1 then the data displayed is the name "AAA",

[image]

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

**Edited-**

I believe you need to fix a few things first-

1. The `opsi` property is missing from the data.
2. The data is not a function.

Now, about your issue that **always id is displaying in the selected option**, the reason behind this is using **reduce** prop. It is mentioned in the documentation's section, [Caveats with reduce](https://vue-select.org/guide/values.html#caveats-with-reduce)-

> The most common issue with reduce is when the component displays your
> reduced value instead of it's label. This happens when you supply Vue
> Select a value or v-model binding with a reduced_ value, but the
> complete option object is not present in the options array.

So, either remove reduce or if wants to continue with the `reduce`, you need to do the following-

1. You are using `v-select` in the loop, which means each `v-select` should have its own `v-model` binding, so create a `selected` variable for each data item and use `v-model="item.selected"`.
2. To display the respected project id's label, from `opsi` array,  put this in the item's `selected` variable by default, like this-

```
detail_data: [{
    "id": 3,
    "project_id": 1,
    "duration_minute": 300,
    "detail": "Text 1",
    "selected": [{
      "id": 1,
      "name": 'AAA'
    }]
  },
  {
    "id": 4,
    "project_id": 2,
    "duration_minute": 203,
    "detail": "Text 2",
    "selected": [{
      "id": 2,
      "name": 'BBB'
    }]
  }
]
```

3. Finally, use it in your template like this-

```
<v-select 
  :options="opsi" 
  :reduce="opsi => opsi.id" 
  label="name"
  v-model="item.selected" 
  :required="!item.project_id"
>
</v-select>
```

Read more about-

[1. Using v-select in the loop.](https://vue-select.org/guide/loops.html)
[2. Display selected text using slots.](https://vue-select.org/api/slots.html#selected-option)

Comment: thanks, but when data project_id = 1, select option shows "AAA". @neha-soni

Comment: didn't get that. Please explain in detail. Maybe this is related to the logic you prepared.

Comment: Hello @neha-soni , I have added a description of the expectations I want.

Comment: I edited the answer, maybe it helps.